# French grammar book similar to English Grammar in Use

Tags: grammaire, ressources

I am looking for a book on French grammar similar to *English Grammar in Use* by Murphy. The qualities I am seeking are explanations in simple French, a lot of exercises and level about A1/A2 maybe B1.

On this site, some people suggested Bescherelle, which is "only" a reference book. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

If Bescherelle does not suit you, you can read "Le BLED" by Edouard Bled and Odette Bled, "Le petit Grevisse
Grammaire française" by Maurice Grevisse  or "La grammaire française" by Nathalie Baccus.

I hope it could help :)